# Is Adobe Flex opensource?

Tags: jquery, apache-flex, extjs, adobe

I want to know is Adobe Flex open source and free means any one can use and sell the product developed using Flex? I am good at logic but whenever it comes to UI, layout, design, CSS then I am very poor in that. I wanted a solution which can solve my UI related issue. I know jQuery ,but then that help me in providing only widgets like grid etc, I want solution which will keep me free from worrying UI related issue.

Is Adobe Flex is the product which can solve my problem. I am looking forward to extjs as well, as a jQuery developer will it be easy for me to learn extjs?

Comment: See this question ["Can i use flex without Flex builder?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1444914/256544) for a better understanding of the Flex ecosystem.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know is adobe flex open source

Yes, most of Adobe Flex is available under a [Mozilla Public License](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Legal+Stuff).

> means any one can use and sell the product developed using flex?

That is formally a question for your lawyers.  But, I Believe so yes, and have a business selling commercial [Flex Components](http://www.flextras.com).

As [Flex moves to Apache](http://incubator.apache.org/flex/), much of Flex will be released under the [Apache 2.0 License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html); which many feel is more liberal than the Mozilla Public License.

However, I am not a lawyer and this does not constitute legal advice.

Answer (score 0):

All the information about licensing can be found here: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Legal+Stuff

Comment: Since [Flex is moving to Apache](http://incubator.apache.org/flex/) I'm not sure that info is still relevant.

Comment: @RIAstar Everything in the link is relevant, since the original question was explicitly related to Adobe Flex.  Adobe Flex will continue, albeit in a "maintenance mode" approach.  I perceive that in a few years, Apache Flex will be the preferred SDK; and Adobe Flex will become less relevant.

Comment: For Flex, this is currently the information to go. Until the entire move is complete, this seems to be the right document, because there are multiple licenses to consider...