# How to set up Flex Unit 4.2 without Flash Builder

Tags: unit-testing, actionscript-3

I'm working on a project that uses the Flash IDE as the compiler and asset manager. This means I'm using as3, with Flash Develop. I am currently unable to setup an environment in which Flex Unit's unit testing environment can be used as there is a lack of documentation for methods other than using Flash Builder's wizard. Guides for MXMLC in [Can i use flex without Flex builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444914/can-i-use-flex-without-flex-builder/1445064#1445064) are not relevant as it uses a different language.

All Apache documentation I have found is either MXML specific, or relies on the wizard in Flash Builder.

Has anyone successfully configured Flex Unit 4.2 with the Flash IDE?

As I have noted, I am not using Flash Builder or the legacy Flex environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i use flex without Flex builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444914/can-i-use-flex-without-flex-builder)

Comment: Please note that Flex and Flex Unit are distinctly different. Flex is an application framework, while Flex Unit is a library that allows TDD or other design practices to be used when developing with AS3 or MXML

Comment: that's not a duplicate, flex unit as mentioned above is a self sufficient framework which supports both flex and pure as3 environment. But setup for as3 can be a little bit tricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pure AS3 projects, you need to use special Flex Unit SWC without Flex dependency. The problem here is to find such build (I also did not manage to find it on official Flex Unit resources), but that [example](https://github.com/simb/FlexUnit-4-Actionscript-Only-Demo) project works fine with pure AS3 projects.

Code example (from [flex unit site](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/FlexUnit+Setting+up+a+project), but sample project above uses the same):

```
public function runTests():void
{
    var core:FlexUnitCore = new FlexUnitCore();

    /**If you don't need graphical test results, comment out the line below and the MXML declaring the TestRunnerBase. **/
    //core.addListener( new UIListener( uiListener ) );
    //core.addListener( new CIListener() );

    /**If you would like to see text output in verbose mode, umcomment either of the follow listeners **/
    core.addListener( new TraceListener() ); //- For AS3 Projects
    //core.addListener( TextListener.getDefaultTextListener( LogEventLevel.DEBUG ) ); - For Flex Projects

    core.run( EchoPanelTest, SampleTest );
}
```